# How to implement a Searchview in android?

Tags: android, searchview

I added some code to oncreate options menu like [this](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html)

```
 SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Also I created a xml file in xml directory and I did what is said in [this](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html).But I don't know how to pass search query and get the result. Executing this getting action bar disappeared.

Comment: The link you provided explains exactly how to do this. It's explained in the [Setting Up the Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#create-sa) section. What is it you are not understanding about those instructions?

Comment: But the query I have entered does not come to `query` variable..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Furthermore if you want have some callback use the code below, on putting some query and fetch it.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Search View Example in android Working Source Code

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzBKpZ4nzNzUajJhNEV2N25qWlU